# Understanding counter-example for - is finite set real (Mathematics Form & Function)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I recently started with Mathematical Form & Function by Saunders Mac Lane. I came across following passage:

> Finitists hold that infinite sets (and geometrical infinities) are
>   just convenient fictions, while only the finite is “real”. This we
>   must later consider. For that matter, is a finite set real? On the
>   fourth day of Christmas did my true love send me four Colley birds or
>   a set of four Colley birds? Where is the set?

I can't understand what author seems to prove with this example. Is he implying that Set is an imaginary concept which we developed but doesn't actually exist in physically. But then it would apply to number itself (four) as the only real things here are the birds. Or is there something else I am missing.

Comment: I think he is criticizing the finitists.  The finitists say (according to the author) that infinite sets are "convenient fictions" and only finite sets are real.  I think the author is countering that all mathematics (or at least set theory) is "convenient" fiction.  Or maybe he is say that the concept of a set is distinct from the objects in the set so although given an infinite number of birds (or numbers) is impossible, having a concept of birds as group (or numbers) of a group isn't.  ... can you provide the *next* paragraph?

Comment: In any event, I think the author would agree with your assessment that $4$ is no more real or unreal then a "set".  As to whether this refutes the finitists or clarifies their position I'm not entirely certain.  I think the author is critiquing finitists.  In my opinion they are worthy of criticisms.  I wouldn't give them much heed.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for assuring my understanding. The author ends the current section here and starts with a new topic (Permutations) after that. However, I am interested to know what's your reason for their (finitists) criticism would be. Is there any practical importance/applications we have for infinite sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing "real" about mathematics, period.

We only define mathematical objects, and we associate some fractions of the reality and certain mathematical constructions, thus, creating models so that they fit the said fractions of reality pretty well. There are no "true" mathematical objects which come uniquely from "reality".